# Error in min(c(bnd$x, bnd$y), na.rm = TRUE) - 1 : non-numeric argument to binary operator in R

Tags: r, contour

I want to draw contour graph with my data by R.
So I am using the modified code from this site(https://theoceancode.netlify.app/post/odv_figures/)
What's different from this site is that my data uses "latitude" instead of "date".

< My code >

```
#Packages
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(reshape2)
library(MBA)
library(mgcv)
library(dplyr)

# Load and screen data
ctd <- read.csv("D:\\2023SCTR.csv")

# Color (ODV)
ODV_colours <- c("#feb483", "#d31f2a", "#ffc000", "#27ab19", "#0db5e6", "#7139fe", "#d16cfa")

#Plotting
tem_sctr <- ggplot(data=ctd, aes(x = latitude, y = depth, z = temperature)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = temperature), size = 1) +
  scale_colour_gradientn(colours = rev(ODV_colours)) +
  labs(y="Depth (m)", x = "Latitude", colour="Temperature (°C)") +
  scale_y_reverse()

tem_sctr

# Now we may interpolate the data
x=ctd$latitude
y=ctd$depth
z=ctd$temperature

ctd_mba <- mba.surf(data.frame(x,y,z),300,300)
dimnames(ctd_mba$xyz.est$z) <- list(ctd_mba$xyz.est$x, ctd_mba$xyz.est$y)
ctd_mba <- melt(ctd_mba$xyz.est$z, varnames = c('latitude', 'depth'), value.name = 'temperature') %>% 
  filter(depth < 0) %>% 
  mutate(temperature = round(temperature, 1))

# Finally we create our gridded result
ggplot(data = ctd_mba, aes(x = latitude, y = depth)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = temperature)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rev(ODV_colours)) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = temperature), binwidth = 2, colour = "black", alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_contour(aes(z = temperature), breaks = 20, colour = "black") +
  ### Activate to see which pixels are real and not interpolated
  # geom_point(data = ctd, aes(x = latitude, y = depth),
  #            colour = 'black', size = 0.2, alpha = 0.4, shape = 8) +
  ###
  labs(y = "Depth (m)", x = "Latitude", fill = "Temperature (°C)") +
  coord_cartesian(expand = 0)

# Create a bounding box
# We want to slightly extend the edges so as to use all of our data
left <- ctd[ctd$latitude == min(ctd$latitude),] %>% 
  select(-temperature) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(latitude = latitude-0.01)
bottom <- ctd %>%
  group_by(latitude) %>% 
  summarise(depth = min(depth)) %>% 
  mutate(depth = depth-0.01)
right <- ctd[ctd$latitude == max(ctd$latitude),] %>% 
  select(-temperature) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(latitude = latitude+0.01)
top <- ctd %>%
  group_by(latitude) %>% 
  summarise(depth = max(depth)) %>% 
  mutate(depth = depth+0.01)

# Now that we have a bounding box we need to 
# screen out the pixels created outside of it
bounding_box_list <- list(bounding_box)
names(bounding_box_list[[1]]) <- c("v","w")
v <- ctd_mba$latitude
w <- ctd_mba$depth
```

**I've been successful so far
**

```
ctd_mba_bound <- ctd_mba[inSide(bounding_box_list, v, w),]
```

**However, using the above code gives the following result:
Error in min(c(bnd$x, bnd$y), na.rm = TRUE) - 1 :
non-numeric argument to binary operator

If you look at the arguments of ctd_mba using the str function, it comes out as num.

What does this mean, and how can I fix it to get the correct result?**

```
ctd_mba_bound <- ctd_mba[inSide(bounding_box_list, v, w),]
```

**However, using the above code gives the following result:
Error in min(c(bnd$x, bnd$y), na.rm = TRUE) - 1 :
non-numeric argument to binary operator

If you look at the arguments of ctd_mba using the str function, it comes out as num.

What does this mean, and how can I fix it to get the correct result?**

Comment: The problem is that we don't have your dataset - can you use `dput` to output just part of it, with which we can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I used dput() function.

> dput(ctd_mba)
structure(list(latitude = numeric(0), depth = numeric(0), temperature = numeric(0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = integer(0))